How can I speed up a workflow that uses a containerized service?
In my GitHub Actions workflow I'm using the services key to define a docker image that should be run (a public docker image, localstack/localstack).
The Docker image gets pulled in from scratch each time I run the workflow.
Given that the service images are loaded and spun up before any jobs execute, I'm not sure the default ways of caching stuff apply.
Is there another way to speed up the process or set up caching another way?

Fundamentally it has to get the image to start the container, so: not really, no.

is it your image or a standard one?

Standard image (localstack/localstack)

@jonrsharpe Yeah obviously but does it have to get it completely fresh every time?

Run your own github actions executor which uses a persistent docker deamon and run your job on it.

Isn't that a bit overkill?
